# Android dependency has different version for the compile and run time: runing FCM dependency

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to use FCM since a  long time but I got problem with android X That I upgraded flutter to the latest version here is flutter doctor:

```
 Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.885], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available
```

and then I used this line to create a new project with androidX :

```
flutter create --androidx  project_name
```

and Then I added in yaml file FCM dependencies :

```
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.2
```

and the I run the project without adding anything else to make sure that The package will make no problem as before ,but unfortunately it did.
 Here is the error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         3.5s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

here is the build.gradle/app :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.cantina_summer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

here is build.gradle/android:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`

with

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'`

Comment: and also upgrade the kotlin version into 1.3.0